# Can you fire keyTyped() function without any input fields?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I just want to ask if you could invisibly type in the JFrame without any input fields and then a sudden action comes out? Just wondering. And if so, how is that possible?

Comment: Even if you could, why would you want to?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do that directly on a **`JFrame`** but inside a **`JFrame`**, there is a **`JComponent`** at least. So you can use **`KeyBinding`** on any **`JComponent`**.

[Related Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Sample:

```
Action doNothing = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //do nothing
    }
};
component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"),
                            "doNothing");
component.getActionMap().put("doNothing",
                             doNothing);
```